# Clarification about Chart control in WPF and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, charts

Does anyone know if the types in the .NET 4.0 release of System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization can be used in WPF?  I'm looking to develop a .NET 4.0 WPF application which will create 2D plots and cannot tell from if the WPF toolkit is now necessary in .NET 4.0.

Comment: They can be used with the control WindowsFormsHost. But I haven't even tried to use these charts with wpf so I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charts in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization are Winforms charts, but they can still be used in WPF if you use a `WindowsFormsHost`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Using WindowsFormsHost will work but I wouldn't enjoy the benefits of WPF.  Seems like the toolkit would be the better option.